# jquery append not working after adding elements

Tags: jquery, append

I also tried live(), but not working... please help

Add Question

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".add_question").click(function(){
        $("#questions").append("<div>How are you?<button class=\"add_answer\">Add answer</button></div>");

      });

      $(".add_answer").click(function(){
          alert("working..");
      });
});
```

Comment: Which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: My button and my div<button class="add_question">Add Question</button>

<div id="questions"></div>

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say it's "not working"? What exactly is or isn't happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live` is not available on newer versions of jQuery so if you want to delegate events use `on`

```
  $("#questions").on("click", ".add_answer", function(){
      alert("working..");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2m36v/

Now is working

```
      $(document).on('click', '.add_question', function() {
        $("#questions").append("<div>How are you?<button class='add_answer'>Add answer</button></div>");

      });
       $(document).on('click', '.add_answer', function() {
          alert("working..");
      });
```